# Why does Chrome FileReader.readAsText strip the xmlns:xsi attribute from local XML files?

Tags: html, google-chrome, schema, filereader

I wrote a simple HTML app that loads local XML files, then allows the user to run them through an XSL Transform and download the results. The app seemed to be working fine until I tried to use one of the resulting files that had been converted by the HTML app running in Chrome. The XML was not well-formed because the 'xmlns:xsi' attribute was missing. I traced it back and found that it is being stripped out on load by Chrome for no apparent reason. FireFox and IE work fine; they don't mutilate the files data at all.

Is this a Chrome bug or just some more of Google's security bumbling? (occurring in Chrome v32.0.1700)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No, use one of the diverse set of browsers out there".

The reason this doesn't work is due to a security concern that Chrome has addressed in a controversial way[1][2][3][4], by blocking XML files from accessing local XSLT files in the same directory, while HTML files can access .CSS files in the same directory just fine.

Across the issues cited above, users have asked for a clearer error message (since the domains, protocols and ports do in fact match), or at least displaying the XML without the styling. Chrome developers have ignored these requests.

Comment: So that would be yes to the "security bumbling"? Do you have a reference to Google specifically addressing this handling (or even generally, I guess)? The response, of just blocking it,seems lazy; I would think if they are going to block direct access for security reasons, they could at least proxy read the XSLT and display the XML in that context.